# How to get the right indent size in python lists?

Tags: indentation, filetype-python, python, tab-characters

In my vimrc I have `filetype indent plugin on`

When I write python code, the indentation mostly looks good, but in lists it is too big:

```
def fun():
    return 'indent looks good'

my_list = [
        'indent too big'
        ]
```

Why is the indent size different in lists from the rest of code? How can I get the same size in lists?

I've tried `set sts=4 sw=4` but the indentation in lists is still too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this section in the python indentation file (`/usr/share/vim/vim82/indent/python.vim` on my machine):

```
" When inside parenthesis: If at the first line below the parenthesis add
" two 'shiftwidth', otherwise same as previous line.
...
return indent(plnum) + (exists("g:pyindent_open_paren") ? eval(g:pyindent_open_paren) : (shiftwidth() * 2)) 
...
```

Changing the `shiftwidth() * 2` to just `shiftwidth()` gives the indentation I want.

My guess is the reason for the double-shiftwidth is to satisfy the extra indentation suggested by [PEP 8 here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) for arguments to functions with long names. But I'd rather have my lists indent correctly and manually fix argument lists when needed.

Comment: If your solution is addressing your problem maybe could you accept it. You can accept your own answer after t,o day. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

With Vim 9.0 that behavior is now configurable.

If you want to disable the indentation of open parenthesis/bracket you can set

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren = shiftwidth()
```